# Is it possible to have a scala macro constrain the type of a method?

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros

Basically I'm imagining the following.

```
trait A[T] {
  def get(idx: Int): U
}
```

The macro comes in the use. Ideally I want to be able to use get(0), get(1) as macros where the proper return type will be known. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Just specify the return type as `Any` and make your macro whitebox (http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/blackbox-whitebox.html#blackbox_and_whitebox_macros). Whitebox macro expansions assume their actual type, not the declared type of the macro definition.